# How Occurrence date of an event is different from the start date?

Tags: cocoa, calendar, eventkit, ekevent

Both CalEvent and EKEvent represents startDate, endDate and occurrenceDate. But since an event object represents the concrete event, with concrete start and end dates. What is the reason to have an occurrenceDate which is always the same as startDate?

Is there a situation when occurrenceDate does not match the startDate of an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the EKEvent.`occurrenceDate` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKEvent/occurrenceDate):

> This value will remain the same even if the event has been detached and its start date has changed.

So if you have a recurring event, and you detach an occurrence of that event from it, creating a new, separate event, the new event will have the same `occurrenceDate` but a different `startDate`.

That seems like it's backwards, but it's what I'm getting from that passage in the docs. You can verify this by experiment by creating a new recurring event in Calendar/iCal and then detaching a subsequent occurrence of it, and looking at the detached event's `startDate` and `occurrenceDate` with Event Kit.

I don't know whether this is equally true or the same way around in Calendar Store, [whose documentation](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/CalendarStoreFramework/Classes/CalEvent_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CalEvent/occurrence) doesn't describe the difference between the `occurrence` and `startDate` properties.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. But if you detach an event, it'll likely have another identifier, so the occurrenceDate won't be useful anyway. And docs indeed are not descriptive on that issue.

Comment: @Kentzo: Yes, the detached event is a separate event. According to the docs, it inherits the `occurenceDate` of the original recurring event, but bears a new `startDate`, which is whichever date it was detached to.

Comment: But then occurrenceDate is useless, since you need both old `UID` and `occurrenceDate` to get original event. I wonder why do you need this, in what situation you can use it.

Comment: As I found, when you 'detach' repeating event (e.g. by modifying start date), UID is preserved. Therefore `occurrence` (and `occurrenceDate`) can be used to get CalEvent (and EKEvent) object by using `eventWithUID:occurrence:`

Answer (score 9):

Well, I just did an experiment.
Here is my recurrent event before and after detaching.

BEFORE DETACHING

```
po calendarItemExternalIdentifier
"68100758-1572-4662-87C8-84F32680D7C2"
po calendarItemIdentifier
"0D3D5906-9C0F-435A-A0BA-7A6B64086E86"
po self.occurrenceDate
2016-02-12 04:00:00 +0000
po startDate
2016-02-12 04:00:00 +0000
po self.isDetached
false
```

AFTER

```
po calendarItemExternalIdentifier
"68100758-1572-4662-87C8-84F32680D7C2/RID=476942400"
po calendarItemIdentifier
"DAD9A39D-BD57-40D6-8615-B57E3AF9387C"
po self.occurrenceDate
2016-02-12 04:05:00 +0000
po startDate
2016-02-12 04:05:00 +0000
po self.isDetached
true
```

The `occurrenceDate` did change which is opposite to what it claims to be. What's interesting as well (and not documented(?)) `calendarItemExternalIdentifier` was changed too by having RID appended to it. RID appears to be a time interval since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001 to the `occurrenceDate`.

Comment: Wow. You are a saint for sharing your discovery. What an incredibly confusing day I've been having.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from Kostia Kim, here is an extension for getting the original occurrence date:

```
extension EKEvent {

    var originalOccurrenceDate: Date? {
        guard self.isDetached, let interval = timeIntervalFromExternalIdentifier else { return nil }
        return Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: interval)
    }

    var timeIntervalFromExternalIdentifier: TimeInterval? {
        let intervalKey = "/RID="
        guard let externalId = calendarItemExternalIdentifier, externalId.contains(intervalKey) else { return nil }

        let identifierSegments = externalId.components(separatedBy: intervalKey)
        guard let lastSegment = identifierSegments.last, let ridInterval = TimeInterval(lastSegment) else { return nil }

        return ridInterval
    }

}
```